# How to read application.properties at the time of ApplicationContext Initialization in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

In my springboot app, I have custom filter classes that make use of properties defined in the application.properties. This Springboot Application is running fine in eclipse with embedded tomcat but is giving below error when I deploy the app in external tomcat 9.

```
    22-Jun-2022 04:28:59.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
    22-Jun-2022 04:29:03.053 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    22-Jun-2022 04:29:11.377 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [com.abc.xyz.filter.CSPFilter]
     java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.abc.xyz.filter.CSPFilter.init(CSPFilter.java:49)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4491)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:969)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

Here is my CSPFilter.java Class:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class CSPFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CSPFilter.class);

    private static final String HEADER_CSP = "Content-Security-Policy";
    private static final String HEADER_CSP_REPORT_ONLY = "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only";
    private static boolean isReportOnly = false;
    private static String policy = "";

    @Autowired
    Environment applicationProperties;

    FilterConfig filterConfig;

    /**
     * init
     */
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.debug("init - fired");
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;

        String configPolicy = applicationProperties.getProperty("cspfilter.policy");
        String reportOnly = applicationProperties.getProperty("cspfilter.policy");
//      logger.info("cspfilter.policy=" + applicationProperties.getProperty("cspfilter.policy"));
//      logger.info("cspfilter.reportOnly=" + applicationProperties.getProperty("cspfilter.reportOnly"));
        // read policy init param
        if (configPolicy != null) {
            logger.debug("Setting policy=" + configPolicy);
            policy = configPolicy;
        }

        // read report only init param
        if (reportOnly != null) {
            logger.debug("Setting isReportOnly=" + reportOnly);
            isReportOnly = Boolean.valueOf(reportOnly);
        }

        logger.debug("init - reportOnly=" + reportOnly + " configPolicy=" + policy);
    }

    /**
     * doFilter
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("doFilter - fired : started");

        String cspHeader = CSPFilter.HEADER_CSP;
        if (CSPFilter.isReportOnly) {
            cspHeader = CSPFilter.HEADER_CSP_REPORT_ONLY;
        }

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpServletResponse.addHeader(cspHeader, policy);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        logger.debug("doFilter - fired : completed");
    }

    /**
     * destroy
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        logger.debug("destroy - fired");
    }
}
```

And my Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class,UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:customProp.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:insert-sql.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:quartz.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:env.properties")
})
@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.xyz.filter","com.abc.xyz.context","com.abc.xyz.captcha" })
@EnableAsync
public class AbcXyz2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AbcXyz2Application .class, args);
    }

}
```

The error is about `String configPolicy = applicationProperties.getProperty("cspfilter.policy");` line. As I understand that the it is not able to read that property value at the time of ApplicationContext Initialization. Is there any alternative way to load&read the properties files in springboot application so that those property values will be available at the time of ApplicationContext initializaion of Springboot app?

Can you please help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Ditch `@WebFilter` and use `@Component` instead. Else the servlet container will start it instead of SPring, leading to lifecycle issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks it workded. But should I also remove the following `@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.xyz.filter"}}`  ?

Comment: filter related errors are gone. But I'm getting the following errors. **` org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@3f58f55d')
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.ELException: Unable to find ExpressionFactory of type: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF)**

Comment: That is totally unrelated to your initial issue and is a result of you deploying to an external tomcat instead of using the embedded one. Why deploy in the first place instead of using the embedded one? And yes you should remove that line as well.

Comment: Our requirement is to use external tomcat (version 9.0.12) instead of embedded one.

Comment: Also we have classes with annotations `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/captcha.jpg")` , `@WebListener `. Should I also remove them and replace `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/captcha.jpg")` with `@RestController @RequestMapping('/captcha.jpg')` and remove `@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.xyz.filter","com.abc.xyz.context","com.abc.xyz.captcha" })` from main class?

Comment: If they require spring control they should be a controller probably. Also the requirement is something I would strongly advice against and would try to get off the table, as building a jar and have your own control is a lot easier. It is also then garantueed to work, if it works locally it works on the server. Now you don't really know.

Comment: Thanks, now my application is loading fine. Will need little of testing. Thanks again.